# State not reset when component toggles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I've been experimenting with conditionally displaying components.

Externally handled:

```
{show && <MyComponent />}
```

Internally handled:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [externalState] = useContext();
    const [state, setState] = useState("")
    
     // Don't render base on some state value
     if(externalState === false) return null; 

    return <input value={state} onChange={e=>setState(e.currentTarget.value)} type="text"/>

}
```

I've noticed that in the second method, when I toggle the Component on and off, the state does not reset. Is there a way to fix this or is the second approach not recommended.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "toggle the Component on and off"? How are you doing that? I don't see any calls to `setState`

Comment: Sorry, updated OP. Essentially I trigger modals using context state. But if I type inside the modal, close it, show it again, the text I typed remains in the second approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you'll see different behaviors with state retention is because the first method will mount or unmount `MyComponent` whenever the condition changes.

If `show` is false, `MyComponent` is not just hidden, it is actually removed from the DOM.

In the second method, only the JSX *returned* from `MyComponent` is removed from the DOM, the rest of the component remains mounted, meaning state is maintained.

As far as "fixing" the problem (most will actually see the loss of state a bug, so this is a different perspective), the simplest method is to continue using option 1. You can certainly use option 2, but you will have to add some extra logic/function calls to reset state each time the internally managed `show` is updated.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Would that mean it's simpler to go with the first approach since I don't have to handle resetting state internally. I can just rely on dom removal to accomplish what I want.

Comment: @Batman I updated the answer to more specifically respond to your question